# shared_ptr not releasing custom malloc in a thread

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

In my code I'm creating a `shared_ptr` inside a lambda in order to save a PNG file as a background task. Unfortunately, even though I have a custom deleter for the `shared_ptr`, it seems the bytes are not deallocated correctly.

The code I use to create the `shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<GLubyte> buffer = std::shared_ptr<GLubyte>((GLubyte*) malloc(*dataLength), [](GLubyte* buffer) {
        free(buffer);
    });
```

And in order to save the file and finally deallocate it:

```
std::thread t([=, buffer = std::move(buffer)]() mutable {
        bool done = writePNGFileFromBuffer(path, buffer.get(), width, height);
        return done;
    });
t.detach();
```

I have tried to put `buffer.reset()` inside the lambda, but although the buffer is null memory is not deallocated. I also have tried to change the creator function to something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<GLubyte> buffer = std::shared_ptr<GLubyte>((GLubyte*) malloc(*dataLength), std::free);
```

But it also doesn't work. Now I have been using the lambda deleter because then I can try to put a breakpoint inside and check `free` is called, but memory is still not released.

Furthermore, I have verified that the release works if I put `free(buffer.get())` inside the lambda, but to put it makes no sense to me, because I'm using `shared_ptr` in order to avoid stuff like this.

Can you help me to release this buffer? Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you know the memory is not deallocated?

Comment: Because it is inside an App and the memory doesn't stop growing when I don't call `free(buffer.get()) `. If I keep calling this function, the App ends crashing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint/trace into your deallocation function to check. If you are using shared_ptr you are probably sharing the pointer, thus preventing deallocation!? If you don't need to share, think about unique_ptr.

Comment: Did you try with a `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: I tried a std::unique_ptr with a custom deleter, but it happened the same :( I'm gonna try again to check if I made some mistake.

Comment: are you testing in visual studio with a debug build? If so it's possible that you are using a debug memory allocator which does not actually free memory, but rather simply marks it as deleted - to aid in debugging. Try the program in release build configuration.

Comment: Personally, I would use `std::vector<GLubyte>`.

Comment: I have implemented std::unique_ptr again and it still fails :(

@RichardHodges It's for an iOS app, so i'm testing in Xcode, but I know it fails because it ends crashing except if I use `free(buffer.get())`. When I do it, the profile debugger shows no memory rise.

@Jarod42 I will try if I it can be used in this context, thanks :)

Comment: there are a couple of problems I can envisage. First is the construction of shared_ptr (see my answer), second is the question of whether you waited for your thread to finish (by joining it?)

Comment: I don't wait for the thread, I detach it with `t.detach();`. I will edit my question to add it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this little test harness to prove that the new/delete was being performed correctly.

Note the use of new / delete[] in the buffer constructor. Your use of malloc/free give the code a bad smell. Resorting to free(ptr.get()) is hiding some other logic problem that you haven't solved. If you leave this in the program it will bite you later.

`proxy` is acting as a replacement for a GLubyte that counts the number allocated and destroyed, so I can confirm with `assert` that every construction has a corresponding destruction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

#define USE_PROXY 1

struct proxy
{
    proxy() {
        ++_count;
    }
    ~proxy() {
        --_count;
    }

    static std::atomic<size_t> _count;
};
std::atomic<size_t> proxy::_count = { 0 };

#if USE_PROXY
using GLubyte = proxy;
#else
//using GLubyte = uint8_t;
#endif

bool writePNGFileFromBuffer(const char* path, const GLubyte* bytes, int width, int height)
{

    return true;
}


auto main() -> int
{
    {
        int dataLength = 10000;

        auto buffer = std::shared_ptr<GLubyte>(new GLubyte[dataLength], 
                                               [](GLubyte* p) { delete[] p; });

        const char* path = "/tmp/foo";
        int width = 100, height = 100;

        std::thread t([=, buffer = std::move(buffer)]() mutable {
            bool done = writePNGFileFromBuffer(path, buffer.get(), width, height);
            return done;
        });
        t.join();
        assert(!buffer);
    }
    assert(proxy::_count == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

for further thought, you may have wondered how a failure case in the `write....` function could be handled. At the moment the return value is being thrown away. There are a few ways we could deal with this - one is to supply a lambda that can be called when the write operation is complete. Another is to wrap the write operation into a std::async.

```
bool writeSharedPNGFileFromBuffer(const char* path, shared_ptr<const GLubyte> bytes, int width, int height)
{
    return writePNGFileFromBuffer(path, bytes.get(), width, height);
}


auto main() -> int
{
    {
        int dataLength = 100;

        auto buffer = std::shared_ptr<GLubyte>(new GLubyte[10000], [](GLubyte* p) { delete[] p; });

        const char* path = "/tmp/foo";
        int width = 100, height = 100;

        auto f = std::async(launch::async, writeSharedPNGFileFromBuffer, path, move(buffer), width, height);
        // f is a std::future - a handle to somewhere the result will eventually land.
        // perform main thread work here...
        // ... and get the return value when we're ready to deal with it
        auto written = f.get();
        cout << "written: " << written << endl;
        assert(!buffer);
    }
    assert(proxy::_count == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was another logic problem, it seems I was saving a reference in writePNGFileFromBuffer! However, using your answer in my code and looking for the mistake has made me find it, so thank you very much for your incredible job.